# Difference between 앉으세요 and 앉으실게요

Tags: grammar, difference, word-choice

I hear very often an office (bank) clerk or a nurse say

> 손님 / 환자분, 여기 **앉으실게요**. (Literally) Customer / Patient, please sit here.

Even if it sounds more polite than '앉으세요', I am not sure if it is grammatically correct. Is using '앉으실게요' in such context grammatical? If not, why?

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't sound grammatical to me, but I think they're trying to hard to sound "polite" by avoiding a command (imperative) form altogether.

There are some such "over-polite" expressions that sound icky to many Koreans yet persist among Korean service providers.  The most notorious example is putting "-시" to every subject.  For example: 커피 나오셨습니다, or 이 스테이크는 고기가 얇으세요 (yes, I really heard that once).

As for why such forms persist, the explanation I heard is that most **reasonable** Koreans consider these forms wrong, but some **unreasonable** grumpy Korean customers with neither proper education nor basic decency thinks that they are the king (literally, "손님은 왕이다" used to be a common phrase in many shops), and that every sentence that's addressed to them must end with "-십니다" or something similar.

(We have a word for those kind of customers: 진상.)

...and guess which kind of customers would make a ruckus (and make the service worker's day miserable) when they don't like the expression they heard?

This news article describes the same story: ["치즈 올라가세요" 손님 왕대접에 망가지는 우리말](http://news.sbs.co.kr/news/endPage.do?news_id=N1002330046)

More news articles I found regarding these expressions:

[[우리말 톺아보기] ‘이쪽으로 앉으실게요’](http://www.hankookilbo.com/v/9c847f40f56d418aa9c67ec28ffa79e2)

[바른 우리말 - 검사 받으실게요](http://world.kbs.co.kr/korean/program/program_koreanlanguage_detail.htm?No=1808)